# Java 7's Files.isReadable() and isWritable() take a long time to return

Tags: java, java-7

I'm currently making the move to Java 7 and I'm trying to convert all of my classes to use the new `java.nio.file` package. At one point, I try to check whether a file is readable and writable with what resembles the following code:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
Path path = Paths.get("testDir/sub1/sub2/test.txt");
myObject.setReadable(Files.isReadable(path));
myObject.setWritable(Files.isWritable(path));
```

When I test this with junit (on Windows 7), both `isReadable();` and `isWritable();` consistently hang for 25 seconds each before they return. This is quite unacceptable. Could this be a Windows limitation?
My application will eventually be running on unix but I have not had a chance to test on it yet. I think I should mention that each file I'm testing was created with the following code:

```
Files.createFile(Paths.get("testDir/sub1/sub2/test.txt"));
```

Is there anything I can do to help speed things up? Thanks!

Edit:
So it seems that `path.toFile().canRead()` returns instantly, same for canWrite(). If it comes to it, I can use those methods but I would really like to only use the java.nio.file package.

Comment: They returned immediately(18ms) after I invoked them.

Comment: Does the same happen if you use [`File#canRead`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead()) and [`File#canWrite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite())?

Comment: @Lonenebula Nope, they all returned instantly :S

Answer (score 0):

What version of JRE are you using?
To solve this issue, update the JRE to 1.7.0_40+

The issue causing this:

> Checking file access on Windows is expensive because it requires
> reading the DACL and computing the effective access to the file. To
> bypass this, the checkAccess implementation on Windows has a fast path
> for the check read case but unfortunately Files.isReadable isn't using
> that fast path.

For more details please see: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7168172